# I need help trying to edit multiple lines in a file, but only in certain locations and not the whole file

Tags: python-3.x

So what I am trying to do is loop through a file to edit certain lines, the problem is there are multiples of the lines I want to edit but I only want to edit them if they are preceded by a specific line.

For example:

```
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                    record("ND") record_key("16")
                    record("XF2") record_key("X") 
                )
            )
symbol "VTL_1KV" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1039 717) 
            )
picture "_XFU_BSV_XF2" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(976 547) 
                composite_key 
            (
                record("ST") record_key("A") 
                record("ND") record_key("29") 
                record("XF2") record_key("TX") 
            )
        )
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
        (
            set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
            origin(1332 556) 
            composite_key 
            (
                record("ST") record_key("A") 
                record("ND") record_key("19") 
                record("XF2") record_key("AX") 
            )
        )
```

lines `record("ND") record_key("16")` and `record("XF2") record_key("X")` appear in multiple places but I only want to edit them if they are in `picture "TR_NAME_XF"`

What I have so far is

```
def editPicture():
    for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):
        if (somefile.startswith(('DTSPSM_')) and somefile.endswith(('.ddl'.lower()))):
            # Read in the file
            with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), 'r') as file :
                contents = file.readlines()
                for line in contents:
                    if (line.startswith(('          picture "TR_NAME_XF"'))):

                        if (next(line).startswith('record("ND")')):
                            do something here
```

I am not sure how to only grab hold of the lines of interest int the picture `"TR_NAME_XF"` set so that they are not edited elsewhere. I have been trying to use `next(line)` and `exit` but have had not had any luck as of yet.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

I have not used regex before and am fairly new to python, I am getting error: unbalanced parenthesis

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), 'r') as file :
            contents = file.readlines()
            re.compile('picture "TR_NAME_XF".*?\(.*?((record\("ND"\) record_key\("{2}"\))|(record\("XF2"\) record_key\("{min,max}"\)))')
            for line in contents:
                line = re.sub('picture "TR_NAME_XF".*?\(.*?((record\("ND"\) record_key\("{2}"\))|(record\("XF2"\) record_key\("{min,max}"\)))', 'record("XF") record_key("{min,max}")' , line)

        with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), "w") as file:
            contents = "".join(contents)
            file.write(contents)
```

I'm finding the documentation a little confusing, I'm not entirely sure what format the (replacement, string) should go in the regex.sub() parentheses...as at the moment nothing is being replaced in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get matching groups that you then regex-replace:

Try this pattern to find the mathces as Groups and regex replace them:

```
picture "TR_NAME_XF".*?\(.*?((record\("ND"\) record_key\("16"\))|(record\("XF2"\) record_key\("X"\)))
```

with Multiline and Dotall.

Explanation:

- the expression uses `.*?` wich is a non.greedy match all to find the inner record after a the `picture "TR_NAME_XF".*?\(`
- the `\(` is the first parenthesis after the linebreak and whitespaces.
- another non-greedy matchall for everything until it matches either one of your  2 looked for records - they are matched as groups
- the match for an open bracked behind the first `.*?` is needed to restrict it to things coming directly behind *this* found picture - not ones further down.

Tested here: https://regexr.com/3ino7

`Mutliline` is needed because it spans multiple lines and `dotall` lets `.` match line-ends as well.

---

Danger (thx to @glibdud):

```
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                    record("ND") record_key("16")
                    record("XF2") record_key("X") 
                )
            )
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                )
            )

picture "TR_NAM E_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                    record("ND") record_key("16")
                    record("XF2") record_key("X") 
                )
            )
```

It will match here as well:

```
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                    record("ND") record_key("16")
```

and

```
picture "TR_NAME_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                )
            )

picture "TR_NAM E_XF" 
            (
                set("ST_ESB-STATION-SCADA") 
                origin(1113 552) 
                composite_key 
                (
                    record("ST") record_key("A") 
                    record("ND") record_key("16")
                    record("XF2") record_key("X")
```

Your total match would contain > 2 "pictures" - you could try to test against that to prevent these "false" matches - need more demodata to refine the regex.

Comment: This assumes all `picture "TR_NAME_XF"` sections have the desired lines. (Which may be true; just noting for the OP.)

Comment: @glibdud changed it a tidbit and provided regexr-fiddle - not quite getting what you mean - he wants to get them only when they are in a `picture "TR_NAME_XF"` ?

Comment: Yes, and this will work as desired if all such sections have the desired lines. But if a `"TR_NAME_XF"` section does not have the desired `record("ND")...` line but is followed by a non `"TR_NAME_XF"` section that does, this will match that.

Comment: In other words, this will match the next `record("ND")...` or `record("XF")...` after a `picture "TR_NAME_XF"`, regardless of whether it's actually in the structure of that `picture "TR_NAME_XF"`.

Comment: I think we can't be sure without more info on the structure of the file.

Comment: Hi guys, all "TR_NAME_XF" sections have the `record("ND")...`  but I forgot to mention the value of `16 and X` can change but they are always located in the same place in the "TR_NAME_XF" section.

Comment: @Ninjasoup change to regex to accomodate for that - f.e. by replacing `ND` with `.{min,max}` - same for `16` (min = minimum number of characters, max = max - or use {2} if they are always 2)

Comment: I just couldn't get this to work for me, ending up doing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097139/i-am-trying-to-edit-a-line-in-a-file-this-line-appears-in-multiple-areas-but-i?noredirect=1#comment83169533_48097139) instead