# I am trying to edit a line in a file, this line appears in multiple areas but I only want to edit some of them

Tags: python-3.x

So I have been looking at other examples of this and have come up with the following:

```
def editPicReplace():
    for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):
        with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), "r") as file:
             filedata = file.readlines()


             index_list = []
        for index, line in enumerate(filedata):
            if line.startswith('            picture "TR_NAME_XF"'):
                index_list.append(index)
                print(index_list)

        for a in index_list:

            for i, line in enumerate(filedata):
                if i == a + 7:
                    filedata[i]= line[:18].replace('2', '') + line[18:]
                    print(line)

        with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), "w") as file:
                    filedata = "".join(filedata)
                    file.write(filedata)
```

at the `print(line)`statement it prints out the correct edit to the required lines but the problem I'm having is the new edit does not get written to the file.

I have mucked around with `fileinput`and with `tempfile`but still had no luck with writing the new edit back to the file.

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Comment: You're not actually changing `filedata`. Try changing `line = line[:18]...` to `filedata[i] = line[:18]...`.

Comment: @glibdud thanks that did it, can't believe I missed that

Comment: Just a comment about performance. Instead of iterating over the entire filedata for every index a. You could also do something like: `for i, line in enumerate(filedata): if i-7 in indexlist: change filedata[i]`